# Git split commit before branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

Let’s suppose you have the following history:

```
         D———G feature1.1
        /
...A-B-C-E-F  feature1
```

Now I want to split B into two commits to get:

```
             D———G feature1.1
            /
...A-B1-B2-C-E-F  feature1
```

You can't just do git rebase -i ... and then choose edit because you get this

```
     B-C-D-G feature1.1
    /
...A-B1-B2-C'-E'-F'  feature1
```

but this is quickly fixed by using a git rebase --onto C' C feature1.1.

Now for a more specific use case. How would you do it if instead feature1 was your master branch, A is your initial commit and you want to split up A. The same technique doesn't work because after the rebase they don't have a shared history anymore.

Comment: You still need to use the same technique: use `rebase --onto`. The target of your `--onto` will be the first half of your split `A`, whatever hash ID that winds up being.

Answer (score 1):

Major ancestry surgery is `git filter-branch` territory, with whatever tools are handiest to do any content alterations.  Sometimes that's easiest to do "while you're there", in a filter-branch snippet, but here it's easier to set up the content ahead of time and just use the filter-branch for its ancestry rewrites.  The stuff you can do without rewriting existing ancestry is make `A---B1---B2`, to start that do

```
git checkout B
git reset A
```

and your work tree is now the `B` content, your index is to the `A` content, and HEAD i.e. your next commit's parent is `A`, so add the `B1` content however's most convenient:

```
git add files whose changes all belong in B1
git add --patch files whose changes partially belong in B1
git reset --patch any hunks you added by mistake
git commit   # this makes B1
git add .    # everything that remains belongs in B2, so add everything
git commit   # this makes B2
```

and now the only thing left is to rewire ancestry, there's no content changes needed. Do local-only rewiring then use `git filter-branch` bake the local history rewrite in to all the rewritten history that depends on it:

```
git replace --graft C B2
git filter-branch -- --all
```